# How to match keys of 2 data frames and create new df with matching keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 DataFrames, the keys of which are as fllows:

df:

```
Index(['artistName', 'artForm/nameOfArt/practicedSkill', 'state', 'district',
       'village', 'pinCode', 'dob/yearOfBirth/date', 'gender', 'phone',
       'email', 'differentlyAbled', 'languages', 'exp',
       'category/SC/ST/OBC/General', 'scheme', 'organisation'],
      dtype='object')
```

df1:

```
Index(['S.NO', 'artForm/nameOfArt/practicedSkill','exp', 'organisation',
   'Complete Address of the organisation/individuals associated',
   'artistName', 'Father's Name', 'dob/yearOfBirth/date', 'gender',
   'languages', 'Address - 1', 'Address - 2', 'State', 'District',
   'Pin Code', 'phone', 'EXPERIENCE', 'scheme', 'Email id of artist ',
   'Submitted By'],
  dtype='object')
```

I want to match the keys and pick the required columns from df1 to create a new df.

My code so far (not working)

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import get_close_matches
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['artistName', 'artForm/nameOfArt/practicedSkill', 'state', 'district', 'village', 'pinCode', 'dob/yearOfBirth/date', 'gender', 'phone', 'email', 'differentlyAbled', 'languages', 'exp', 'artAcademy', 'category/SC/ST/OBC/General', 'scheme'])
df1 = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Culture\\Madur.xlsx")
df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
df1.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
seq = [r for r in df.keys() if get_close_matches(r, df1.keys(), n=1, cutoff = .50)]
seq
```

seq =

```
    ['artistName',
 'artForm/nameOfArt/practicedSkill',
 'state',
 'district',
 'village',
 'pinCode',
 'dob/yearOfBirth/date',
 'gender',
 'phone',
 'email',
 'languages',
 'exp',
 'scheme',
 'organisation']
```

What I want is to pick the columns from the `seq` variable and make a df. There are several files that need to be compared like this with `df`.

I am able to extract the columns I need to pick from `df1` but how do I do it? The 'finalList' contains the list of columns need to be picked from `df1`.

Comment: To make this easier to answer, I suggest you add two smaller dataframes, and the result of `seq` as easy Python code we can copy-paste into our environments. Making an [MCVE] is usually the best route to get good, concise answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there - Pandas dataframes accept lists of column names without problem:

```
seq = [r for r in df1.keys() if get_close_matches(r, df.keys(), n=1, cutoff = .50)]
df2 = df1[seq]
```

Comment: I did not get it. I need data from df1 for the keys that fulfil the `get_close_matches` condition in df2. Also, I deleted the duplicate question :). So it should be `df2 = df1[finalList]`, I suppose.

Comment: @KaranGupta I changed the first line as well according to that specification (You need to collect the actual keys from the dataframe you want to filter).

Comment: yeah it worked. Let me check it properly and I'll accept your answer. like you said...patience :P

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question right this should work:

```
  df_cols = df.columns
  df1_cols = df_1.columns

  new_col = []
  for col in df_cols:
      if col in df1_cols:
           new_col.append(col)

 df_new = df[new_col]
```

Comment: I had a made a small mistake in the last line. I have corrected it. Can you please check. If posssible add some sample df to the question.